# TCPDF html table not drawing correctly

Tags: php, html, html-table, tcpdf

I'm having trouble with html tables and tcpdf.

The PHP code:

```
$tbl = <<<EOD
<TABLE width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <TR>
        <TD>
            <STRONG>Four corners - The open road</STRONG>
        </TD>
        <TD>
            <STRONG>2014-07-22 14:45:25</STRONG>
        </TD>
        <TD ALIGN="right">
            <STRONG>H08</STRONG>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>
            <STRONG>Four corners - The open road</STRONG>
        </TD>
        <TD>
            <STRONG>2014-07-22 14:45:25</STRONG>
        </TD>
        <TD ALIGN="right">
            <STRONG>H08</STRONG>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>        
EOD;
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
```

But the cells on each row is offset in the table in the pdf. (See image: [image])

The first row is shifted by about 26 pixel and the second about 41 pixels

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, the problem was that I use capital letters for the tags :s

Comment: I am not using capita letter for tags still face above problem.